# How to output x,y,w,h only when mouse is released with JFrame in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a sample Java Swing App below, it now outputs X,Y,W,H whenever the JFrame is moved or resized. What I want is to ONLY output X,Y,W,H when the mouse is released, so what I mean by that is : I need to do some processing after the new JFrame location and size is final, not during the resizing process, I want to save the final X,Y,W,H.

But right now if I move the JFrame from [X=100,Y=200] to [X=150,Y=200], it will save it 50 times because during the moving process, X value is changed from 100 to 150, so it will save every time X is changed, which is unnecessary, I only want it to save the final result [ X=150,Y=200 ] after the mouse is released, how to achieve that ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseMotionEventDemo extends JPanel
{
  static JFrame frame=new JFrame();
  
  public MouseMotionEventDemo()
  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));
    
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener()
    {
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) { saveXYWH(frame); }
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { saveXYWH(frame); }
      public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { }
      public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) { }
    });
  }
  
  void saveXYWH(JFrame frame)
  {
    System.out.println("Demo [ X = "+frame.getLocation().x+" , Y = "+frame.getLocation().y+" | W = "+frame.getSize().width+" , H = "+frame.getSize().height+" ]");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); } });
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    MouseMotionEventDemo demo=new MouseMotionEventDemo();
    frame.setContentPane(demo);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible - or at least not in a simple way - because the handling of the mouse is done out of a context you can manage.  Instead, why I've done in the past, is used a Swing `Timer` with a shortish delay.  So each time `componentResized` is called, you would restart the `Timer` and until there are no updates (within a reasonable amount of time), the `Timer` won't trigger.

Comment: Implement a [`MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) and do it on the [`mouseReleased`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseReleased-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-) event?

Comment: @MadProgrammer why not just store the values in fields every time the component is resized, and hook the mouseReleased event to save the latest values?

Comment: @DavidConrad Because you can't trap the mouse events which are used by the OS to resize or move the window - because that's managed by the OS, not Java - so a `MouseListener` in this context won't work

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, of course. My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I think I've got a simple solution, I'll wait for 2 days, if no one else has a better answer, I'll post it ^_^ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My objective is to :

[1] Save the final X,Y,W,H

[2] Only save them once, not multiple times during the moving or resizing process.

I came up with the following solution :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseMotionEventDemo extends JPanel
{
  static JFrame frame=new JFrame();
  
  public MouseMotionEventDemo()
  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));

    frame.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
    {
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
      {
//        displayMessage("Focus gained",e);
      }

      public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
      {
        displayMessage("Focus lost",e);
        saveXYWH(frame);
      }

      void displayMessage(String prefix,FocusEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println(prefix
                           +(e.isTemporary() ? " (temporary)" : "")+" : < "
                           +e.getComponent().getName()+" > ; Opposite component : < "
                           +(e.getOppositeComponent()!=null ? e.getOppositeComponent().getName() : "null")+" >");
      }
    });
  }
  
  static void saveXYWH(JFrame frame)
  {
    Out("saveXYWH [ X = "+frame.getLocation().x+" , Y = "+frame.getLocation().y+" | W = "+frame.getSize().width+" , H = "+frame.getSize().height+" ]");
  }

  private static void Out(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); } });
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    MouseMotionEventDemo demo=new MouseMotionEventDemo();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { saveXYWH(frame);System.exit(0); }
    });
    frame.setContentPane(demo);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

So the X,Y,W,H values are only saved in one of the 3 situations below :

[1] When the user clicks away from the JFrame, to focus on some other component.

[2] When the user minimized the JFrame.

[3] When the user closes the JFrame window.

In any one of the above situations, focus will be lost on this JFrame, and the X,Y,W,H values can be caught by the FocusListener's focusLost() method and saved, it's only saved once, and it's the final values.

Comment: Wait... if it is your goal to actually SAVE the window's bounds (presumably to restore it when loading it again), why not add that part into the `dispose()` method (overwrite), or add a `addWindowListener()->WindowListener->windowIconified` or `windowClosing` listener?

Comment: Your second objective is to save once *during* the move - that is not the final coordinates. And it seems the events your solution uses are not the same you had in your objective. But it seems good enough.

Comment: I agree, I just want a SIMPLE solution to save the JFrame's last position and size [ only once ], so I may not even need the focus listerner, I just need the windowClosing(), do the saving there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that too many events are fired in a short timeframe and you have a lengthy calculation that should get triggered only after the last of these events.

How about a deferred invocation? Whenever the window is moved/resized, a timer is started/reset. Only when the events pause for a moment the timer gets to fire, and the calculation takes place.

The advantage of this pattern is that you can use it wherever you find events coming in too fast and only on the last one you can react.

Here is an example based on your save method:

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ResizeFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Timer timer;
    
    public ResizeFrame() {
        initComponents();
        
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                timer.restart();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                timer.restart();
            }
            
        });
        
        timer = new Timer(500, ae -> saveXYWH(this));
    }
    
    void saveXYWH(JFrame frame)
    {
        timer.stop();
        System.out.println("Demo [ X = "+frame.getLocation().x+" , Y = "+frame.getLocation().y+" | W = "+frame.getSize().width+" , H = "+frame.getSize().height+" ]");
    }    
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ResizeFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for you here, but it uses JNativeHook, which uses JNI:

- https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook
- downloadable releases here: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases), .
- Also make sure to use version 2.2.2 or later, the previous builds are a bit buggy on Windows, not triggering all events

So here the central class:

```
package gui.windows.mousedraghelper;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseListener;


public class MouseDragHelper implements AutoCloseable {

    private final Consumer<ComponentEvent> mLambda;

    ComponentEvent mLastDragEvent;

    public MouseDragHelper(final Component pWindow, final Consumer<ComponentEvent> pLambda) throws NativeHookException {
        mLambda = pLambda;

        GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new NativeMouseListener() {
            @Override public void nativeMousePressed(final NativeMouseEvent pNativeMouseEvent) {
                mLastDragEvent = null;
            }
            @Override public void nativeMouseReleased(final NativeMouseEvent pNativeMouseEvent) {
                checkRaiseEvent();
            }
        });
        pWindow.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override public void componentMoved(final ComponentEvent pE) {
                mLastDragEvent = pE;
            }
        });
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }

    protected void checkRaiseEvent() {
        final ComponentEvent lde = mLastDragEvent;
        if (lde != null) SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> mLambda.accept(lde));
    }

    @Override public void close() {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        } catch (final NativeHookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            /* we could actually simply ignore this */
        }
    }

}
```

Along with the external example (window controlled from the outside):

```
package gui.windows.mousedraghelper;

import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.NativeHookException;


public class Test_MouseDragHelper_External {



    static class TestFrame extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7239078731343703120L;

        public TestFrame() {
            setTitle("MouseDragHelper - External Test");
            setBounds(400, 300, 400, 300);
        }
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) throws NativeHookException {
        final TestFrame window = new TestFrame();

        // we need this to catch the addWindowListener->WindowAdapter->windowClosed event
        // we do NOT need this when WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE is specified
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        window.setVisible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource") final MouseDragHelper mdh = new MouseDragHelper(window, e -> handleWindowDragDone(e));
        window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override public void windowClosed(final WindowEvent pE) {
                mdh.close();
            }
        });

    }

    static private void handleWindowDragDone(final ComponentEvent pE) {
        System.out.println("The window was just dragged and released: " + pE);
    }



}
```

And the internal example (window controlled from its inside, which you will probably use in your code):

```
package gui.windows.mousedraghelper;

import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.NativeHookException;


public class Test_MouseDragHelper_Internal {



    static class TestFrame extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3161758860296277990L;

        private final MouseDragHelper mMouseDragHelper;

        public TestFrame() throws NativeHookException {
            mMouseDragHelper = new MouseDragHelper(this, e -> dragDone(e));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("MouseDragHelper - Internal Test");
            setBounds(400, 300, 400, 300);
        }

        @Override public void dispose() {
            mMouseDragHelper.close();
            super.dispose();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-method") private void dragDone(final ComponentEvent pE) {
            System.out.println("MouseDragHelper.TestFrame.dragDone() " + pE);
        }
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) throws NativeHookException {
        final TestFrame window = new TestFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }



}
```

In both the internal and external examples I have made sure to also unregister the native hooks again, because that library uses a Thread that is no daemon thread. So the JVM would not shut down on its own, unless you used `System.exit()` or `window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`, but that is rather unclean.

// EDIT 1: I could also have added the 'discard/unload' part into the MouseDragHelper class itself, but then I'd have to take care of a lot more things, like if it's a JFrame/JWindow/Frame/Window or any other class... So I decided to leave the discarding to the ouside, the creator, and simply hint at it by making it `AutoCloseable`, which will give resource warnings when used.